# Let $f(z)$ be analytic; show that...

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

a) Let $f(z)$ be analytic; show that

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}\right)|f(z)|^2=4|f'(z)|^2$$

I know the definition of analytic but when I do the partial derivatives are am not arriving at the conclusion.

b) Let $f_1(z),f_2(z),...,f_n(z)\in H(\Omega).$ Show that $$|f_1(z)|^2+|f_2(z)|^2+...+|f_n(z)|^2$$
in harmonic on $\Omega$ only if all the functions $f_k(z) (k=1,2,...,n)$ are constant.

how can I show that the sum of the squared functions are harmonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$**

Note that we can write

$$\frac{df(z)}{dz}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)f(z)\\\\
\frac{df(\bar z)}{d\bar z}=\frac12 \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)f(\bar z)$$

Note that from the Cauchy-Riemann equations

$$\frac12\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)f(z)=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)f(\bar z)=0$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
4|f'(z)|^2&=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)f(z)f(\bar z)\\\\&=\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}\right)|f(z)|^2
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$**

Let $f=u+iv$ so that $\bar f = u-iv$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}\right)|f(z)|^2&=2u\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}\right)u+2v\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}\right)v\\\\
&+2\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)^2 \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

Since $f$ is analytic, both $u$ and $v$ are harmonic and the first and second terms on the right-hand side of $(1)$ vanish.  Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we can write $(1)$ as

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}\right)|f(z)|^2=4\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+4\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 \tag 2$$

Using $f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, we find that

$$|f'(z)|^2=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 \tag 3$$

whereupon comparing $(2)$ and $(3)$ reveals the expected result.